# i3wm: Switching to workspaces and moving container to (same) workspace map to different workspaces

Tags: i3

Hey all,

this problem has me stumped:

### Current Behavior

My i3 config has the following workspacewise:

```
    bindsym $mod+grave workspace h0me
    bindsym $mod+1 workspace term1nal
    bindsym $mod+2 workspace co2e
    bindsym $mod+3 workspace teleg3am
    bindsym $mod+4 workspace edi4or

    bindsym $mod+Shift+grave move container to workspace h0me
    bindsym $mod+Shift+1 move container to workspace term1nal
    bindsym $mod+Shift+2 move container to workspace co2e
    bindsym $mod+Shift+3 move container to workspace teleg3am
    bindsym $mod+Shift+4 move container to workspace edi4or
```

My polybar has the following:

```
    ws-icon-0 = h0me;a
    ws-icon-1 = term1nal;b
    ws-icon-2 = co2e;c
    ws-icon-3 = teleg3am;d
    ws-icon-4 = edi4or;e
```

Where a through e are icons.

I would expect polybar to display the items next to the name, both when I switch to a new workspace and when I move a container there (polybar is configured accordingly).

However, polybar does only display both icon and name, when I move a container to a new workspace. This workspace is then not mapped to `$mod+1`; I can only swtich to that workspace by searching or cycling through all workspaces.

When I switch to a workspace, I get a new workspace with the same name, but no icon.

This behaviour only holds for workspaces 1 through 3, all others work accordingly.

### Environment

Output of `i3 --moreversion 2>&-`:

```
i3 version: 
I am running i3-gaps version 4.15.0.1 on Arch linux with polybar.
```

```
Logfile URL: https://logs.i3wm.org/logs/5746196614217728.bz2
```

```
- Linux Distribution & Version: Arch Linux Kernel 4.17.2-1
- Are you using a compositor (e.g., xcompmgr or compton): compton
```

[image: 2018-06-27-144015_1920x1080_scrot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you're mapping these icons via polybar and not the i3 config file? Not saying there's anything wrong with doing it that way, I'm simply able to do what it seems you're describing entirely within i3:

```
bindsym $mod+1 workspace 1: 
bindsym $mod+2 workspace 2: 
bindsym $mod+3 workspace 3: 
bindsym $mod+4 workspace 4: 

bindsym $mod+Shift+1 move container to workspace 1: 
bindsym $mod+Shift+2 move container to workspace 2: 
bindsym $mod+Shift+3 move container to workspace 3: 
bindsym $mod+Shift+4 move container to workspace 4: 
```

The boxes are fontawesome icons which I directly copied/pasted into the config file. I decided I liked having an icon only to describe the workspace, as I tend to do certain tasks only on certain workspaces (e.g., workspace 2 is web browsing, workspace 3 is terminal/code editing), but you could just as easily do your "h0me *icon*" setup.

Perhaps shifting this into the i3 config file instead of through polybar may get you the results you want.

[image: i3 setup example]

**Edit** As requested, I've attached my polybar config file:

```
;=====================================================
;
;   To learn more about how to configure Polybar
;   go to https://github.com/jaagr/polybar
;
;   The README contains alot of information
;
;=====================================================

[global/wm]
margin-top = 100
margin-bottom = 100

[colors]
fg = ${xrdb:color7}
modfg = ${xrdb:color1}
bg = ${xrdb:color0}

white = #d1d1d1
gray = #585858
black = #ce1d1d1d
red = #c795ae
blue = #95aec7
yellow = #c7ae95
green = #aec795


[bar/example]
width = 100%
height = 41
top = true
;margin-top = 100

border-top-size = 1  # creating top border space
offset-y = -3   # aligning tray icons with rest of bar
monitor = ${env:MONITOR:}

;background = #141021
background = #000f0f0f # This is the hexcode for transparency (also used in powermenu)
foreground = #c4b7c5


fixed-center = false

font-0 = FontAwesome:pixelsize=10;0
font-1 = PragmataPro Nerd Font:pixelsize=10;0
font-2 = "Font Awesome 5 Free:style=Regular:pixelsize=10;1"
font-3 = "Font Awesome 5 Free:style=Solid:pixelsize=10;1"
font-4 = "Font Awesome 5 Brands:pixelsize=10;1"

modules-left = i3
modules-center = date
modules-right = wireless-network cpu memory filesystem filesystem2 temperature pulseaudio backlight battery powermenu

tray-position = right
;tray-maxsize = 41
tray-background = #000f0f0f
tray-foreground= #000f0f0f

scroll-up = i3wm-wsnext
scroll-down = i3wm-wsprev


overline-size = 2
overline-color = ${colors.white}
underline-size = 4
underline-color = ${colors.white}

;override-redirect = true
;wm-restack = i3


[module/i3]
type = internal/i3

pin-workspaces = true
strip-wsnumbers = true
index-sort = true
enable-scroll = false

format = <label-state> 
format-padding-right = 2

label-unfocused-foreground = #8a7f8f
label-unfocused-padding = 1

label-focused-foreground = #c16772
label-focused-padding = 1

label-urgent-foreground = #e4b226
label-urgent-padding = 1


[module/filesystem]
type = internal/fs

; Mountpoints to display
mount-0 = /

label-mounted =  %free%
format-mounted-padding = 2

; Seconds to sleep between updates
; Default: 30
; interval = 10

; Display fixed precision values
; Default: false
fixed-values = true

; Spacing between entries
; Default: 2
spacing = 6




[module/filesystem2]
type = internal/fs

; Mountpoints to display
mount-0 = /media/<my_name>/Data

label-mounted =  %free%
format-mounted-padding = 2

; Seconds to sleep between updates
; Default: 30
; interval = 10

; Display fixed precision values
; Default: false
fixed-values = true

; Spacing between entries
; Default: 2
spacing = 6





[module/cpu]
type = internal/cpu

interval = 1

format = <label>
format-padding = 2

label =  %percentage%%


[module/memory]
type = internal/memory

interval = 1

format = <label>
format-padding = 2

label =  %gb_used% (%percentage_used%%)


[module/temperature]
type = internal/temperature

interval = 1

thermal-zone = 0

warn-temperature = 74

format = <ramp> <label>
format-padding = 2

format-warn = <ramp> <label-warn>
format-warn-padding = 2

label = %temperature-c%

label-warn = %temperature-c%
label-warn-foreground = #e4b226

ramp-0 = 
ramp-1 = 
ramp-2 = 
ramp-3 = 
ramp-4 = 


[module/date]
type = internal/date

interval = 1

date = %a %b %d, 
time = %H:%M:%S

date-alt = %A, %d %B %Y
time-alt = %H:%M:%S

format = <label>
format-padding = 2

label =  %date% %time%


[module/battery]
; Note - if battery isn't showing, try BAT0 or BAT1, etc.
type = internal/battery

full-at = 95

battery = BAT1
adapter = ACAD

poll-interval = 5

format-charging = <animation-charging> <label-charging>
format-charging-padding = 2

format-discharging = <ramp-capacity> <label-discharging>
format-discharging-padding = 2

format-full = <ramp-capacity> <label-full>
format-full-padding = 2

label-charging = %percentage%%

label-discharging = %percentage%%

label-full = %percentage%%

ramp-capacity-0 = 
ramp-capacity-1 = 
ramp-capacity-2 = 
ramp-capacity-3 = 
ramp-capacity-4 = 

animation-charging-0 = 
animation-charging-1 = 
animation-charging-2 = 
animation-charging-3 = 
animation-charging-4 = 
animation-charging-framerate = 500


[module/backlight]
type = internal/backlight

card = intel_backlight

format = <label>
format-padding = 2

label =  %percentage%%


[module/pulseaudio]
type = internal/pulseaudio
; List sinks via `pactl list sinks` and look at the Name field

sink = alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
;interval = 1

format-volume-padding = 2
format-volume = <ramp-volume> <label-volume>
ramp-volume-0 = 
ramp-volume-1 = 
ramp-volume-2 = 

format-muted-padding = 2
label-muted =  0%


[module/powermenu]
type = custom/menu

label-open =   

label-close = cancel

label-close-background = #000f0f0f
label-close-foreground = #ffeefc
label-open-padding-left = 4
label-open-padding-right = 3
label-close-padding = 3

menu-0-0 = lock
menu-0-0-exec = ~/scripts/lock.sh
menu-0-0-background = #000f0f0f
menu-0-0-foreground = #c05c47
menu-0-0-padding-right = 3

menu-0-1 = reboot
menu-0-1-exec = menu-open-1
menu-0-1-background = #000f0f0f
menu-0-1-foreground = #c05c47
menu-0-1-padding-right = 3

menu-0-2 = power off
menu-0-2-exec = menu-open-2
menu-0-2-background = #000f0f0f
menu-0-2-foreground = #c05c47
menu-0-2-padding-right = 3

menu-1-0 = reboot?  
menu-1-0-exec = reboot
menu-1-0-background = #000f0f0f
menu-1-0-foreground = #e4b226
menu-1-0-padding-right = 3

menu-2-0 = power off?  
menu-2-0-exec = poweroff
menu-2-0-background = #000f0f0f
menu-2-0-foreground = #e4b226
menu-2-0-padding-right = 3


[module/wireless-network]
type = internal/network

; Look at ifconfig for interface
interface = wlo1

format-connected = <label-connected>
format-connected-padding = 2

format-disconnected = <label-disconnected>
format-disconnected-padding = 2

label-connected =  %essid%

label-disconnected =  None
```

Comment: okay, cool. I will try this and get back here if it worked

Comment: Would you mind sharing your respective polybar config? Not sure how you get your icons "over there"

Comment: Sure thing, just added it at the bottom of my answer. Glad to have helped!

Comment: Sorry for reviving an old topic but, how can I get a complete list of the codes for icons from font-awesome in order to use them?

Comment: I use their "cheatsheet", and I don't actually use the codes at all. I copy/paste the images directly into my text editor (in my case, Sublime 3). You must have the Fontawesome font installed on your machine in order for the icons to actually register.

https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet